# How to call C++/CLI from C++/CLI and C# in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I learned not long ago that C++/CLI is the way to go to use unmanaged C++ code. I was able to figure out how to call code from a C++ project in a C++/CLI project with the C++ code being in a static library. The C++ code is in a static library and the C++/CLI code in in a Win32 application.

Then I wanted to transform the C++/CLI project into a static library (from now on known as wrapper) and create another "consumer" project (either C++/CLI or C#) to call on the wrapper. This is the place where I'm stuck.

In C#, linking project is so easy. All you need is to add a reference from the consumer project to the library project. How do you do that from either a C++/CLI or C# project to a C++/CLI project?

Okay, so that is the main question. My final goal is to be able to go from C# to C++/CLI to C++ freely, either using DLLs or static libraries, but I've got to solve my currently problem first.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you can't add a reference to a C++/CLI static library (.lib) because .libs are C++-specific. Instead you need to create the C++/CLI project as a **Class Library** project which compiles into a .NET assembly (a DLL). The resulting DLL can be added as a reference from the C# project.

One more thing, I don't recommend using C++/CLI to create wrappers for unmanaged C++ classes. In those cases it's better to turn the classes into COM classes (using ATL). Since .NET is backwards- and forwards-compatible with COM, COM classes can be used from C# directly without requiring you to create any wrappers. C++/CLI is good for when you need to mix managed and unmanaged code in the same place, but whenever you find yourself creating wrappers, you should consider using COM instead.